# How to add a timestamp comment to my output files?

Tags: javascript, less, concatenation, gulp, minify

I have Gulp setup to convert my LESS files to CSS, concatenate them and minify them. Same for my JS. I'd like to have a small comment at the start of each minified CSS/JS output file that contains the time the file was built. Something that will allow me to see which file is being used on production, at a glance, without having to search thru the minified code for the update.

Something like:

> /* Generated at: 02-21-2015 @ 08:00:00 */

I've yet to see any way to do this. I'm familiar with the Gulp rev plugin, but that's more for cache busting, and I definitely don't want to bust the cache on these files. I just need to see at a glance when the file was generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like gulp-header was what I wanted.

```
var header = require('gulp-header'),
    d = new Date(),
    headerComment = '/*Generated on:' + d + '*/';
```

and then in my task, add this in as a pipe:

```
.pipe(header(headerComment))
```